# How to Execute set of SQL statements using IF ELSE in SPARK SQL/DataBricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am getting an error when i execute below code in databricks

```
%sql
if((select column from database.temp_Table)<= 0)
   BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS database.Table1;
        CREATE TABLE database.Table1(column1 datatype,column2 datatype......columnN datatype) USING 
       DELTA;
        SELECT * INTO database.Table1 FROM database.Table3;
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS database.Table2;
        CREATE TABLE database.Table2(column1 datatype,column2 datatype......columnN datatype) USING 
         DELTA;
        SELECT * INTO database.Table2 FROM database.Table3;
   END
```

Below is the error i am facing.

```
extraneous input 'if' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'DESC', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SHOW', 'USE', 'DROP', 'ALTER', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'START', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'MERGE', 'UPDATE', 'CONVERT', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'LIST', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD', 'OPTIMIZE', 'COPY'}(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
if((select column from database.temp_Table)<= 0)
^^^
   BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS **
```

*Please help me in implementing  if else in databricks spark sql to execute set of sql statements instead of returning values.Thanks in advance.*

Comment: in spark you should use `case when x then y else z end`

Comment: are you looking for this - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#if ?

Comment: Thanks chlebek & someshwar kale.Those ways are working for values but not to execute set of sql statements.

Comment: Hey everyone..
I found a workaround for this.PFB

```if condition:
   sqlContext.sql("Truncate table database.table1;Insert into database.table1 from database.table3");
   print('Loaded Table1');
else:
   sqlContext.sql("Truncate table database.table2;Insert into database.table2 from database.table3");
   print('Loaded Table2');```

In this scenario..My condition is the value of the column from a table in databricks.For that used rdd.collect() and read that row by row()